# Deserializing json into classes

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have the following json string:

```
[
   {
      "Key":"A",
      "Value":null
   },
   {
      "Key":"B",
      "Value":"18"
   },
   {
      "Key":"C",
      "Value":"False"
   },
   {
      "Key":"D",
      "Value":"BOB"
   }
]
```

I would like to be able to deserialize into the following objects:

```
public class ModelOne
{
    public int? A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set;}
}

public class ModelTwo
{
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

We thought about using `var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelOne>(json);` but clearly the json string is a list of Key and Value so that wouldn't work.

In an ideal world we would like to parse the json and match the **Key** to the *Property Name* and set the **Value** according to the property type. We could use a similar function to the above which accepts an anonymous type we're just not sure where to start so would be very greatful for some feedback and or assistance.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The json array represents some data points we receive from an external api call.

ModelOne and ModelTwo are each view models in our MVC project we would like to pre-populate.

Comment: Why do you want to be able to deserialize one array into two (or fewer, or more?) objects? Just deserialize into a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, and process the list yourself. You'd have to do the same in a custom converter anyway.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=ARnkSknC6mej6lnMAzVW then map it into whatever data structure you want.

Comment: Preprocess your JSON to the format your service needs, or postprocess the JSON your service gets into the data structure your model needs. Personally, I would lean toward the first one, because JavaScript is more flexible like that, but honestly, it's a coin flip.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for all of your comments but notably both of @mjwills and @Heretic Monkey you really helped.

In the (end against my better judgement) I decided to use a little reflection.

```
public T ConvertDataMapToModel<T>(T item, List<Data> list)
{
    Type itemType = typeof(T);
    var response = (T)item;
    var props = response.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        string propName = prop.Name;
        string listValue = (string)(from c in list where c.Key == prop.Name select c.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(listValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(listValue))
        {
            PropertyInfo pInstance = itemType.GetProperty(propName);
            Type pInstancePropertyType = pInstance.PropertyType;
    
            if (pInstancePropertyType.IsGenericType && pInstancePropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                pInstancePropertyType = pInstancePropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }

            TypeCode typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(pInstancePropertyType);
            switch (typeCode)
            {
                case TypeCode.Boolean:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToBoolean(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Byte:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToByte(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Char:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToChar(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.DateTime:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToDateTime(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.DBNull:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.DBNull);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToDecimal(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Double:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToDouble(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Empty:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, "");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToInt16(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToInt32(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToInt64(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.SByte:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToSByte(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Single:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToSingle(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.String:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToString(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt16:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToUInt16(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToUInt32(listValue));
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                    pInstance.SetValue(response, Convert.ToUInt64(listValue));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```